# Cannot remove icon from Start menu on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-store, uwp

I removed the Windows Store versions of Office so I could install them from the installer, but the store version of PowerPoint still is on my start menu. I have tried googling on how to remove it, but to no avail. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the Windows Store versions of Office, the word and the excel are removed at the same time, but the powerpoint is not removed. It may be two reasons:

1. Office has not been completely uninstalled clean.
2. The version of powerpoint in Office is different from the version of current powerpoint in the Start menu?

We can try to remove it as below:

[image]

If it does not work, we can refer to the ways in the article:
[9 ways to remove desktop programs and modern apps in Windows](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/six-ways-removeuninstall-windows-programs-and-apps)